# XML Data from a webserver not displaying in mobile, mac browsers. Able to see in windows browsers

Tags: xml, macos, xslt, browser

I am having xml data which is using xsl internally. In windows browsers it is displaying properly. But on a mac machine and on mobile devices the page is blank. Here is a sample code for one of the xml and xsl file.
XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pageTemplate.xsl"?>
<page>
<pagehead>
<generator>Sage Accpac SDK 6.8A</generator>
<keywords>AP 68A</keywords>
<pagetitle>Accounts Payable</pagetitle>
<pagedate>2020-Nov-06</pagedate>
</pagehead>
<pagebody>
<header />
<application name="Accounts Payable" version="6.8A">
<viewlist>
<view name="AP0001" desc="Company Options" dllname="APP01">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APP01" desc="Company Options" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0002" desc="Invoicing Options" dllname="APP02">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APP02" desc="Invoicing Options" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0003" desc="Payment and Aging Options" dllname="APP03">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APP03" desc="Payment and Aging Options" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0001" desc="Company Options" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0004" desc="Integration Options" dllname="APP04">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APP04" desc="Integration Options" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0005" desc="Distribution Codes" dllname="APRDC">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APRDC" desc="Distribution Codes" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0006" desc="Account Sets" dllname="APRAS">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APRAS" desc="Account Sets" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0007" desc="1099 / CPRS Codes" dllname="APCLX">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APCLX" desc="1099 / CPRS Codes" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0008" desc="Distribution Set Details" dllname="APDSD">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APDSD" desc="Distribution Set Details" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0009" desc="Distribution Sets" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0009" desc="Distribution Sets" dllname="APDSH">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APDSH" desc="Distribution Sets" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0008" desc="Distribution Set Details" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0010" desc="Payment Codes" dllname="APPTP">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APPTP" desc="Payment Codes" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0011" desc="Terms Payment Schedule" dllname="APRTB">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APRTB" desc="Terms Payment Schedule" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0012" desc="Terms" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0012" desc="Terms" dllname="APRTA">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APRTA" desc="Terms" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0011" desc="Terms Payment Schedule" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0013" desc="1099 / CPRS Amounts" dllname="APCCS">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APCCS" desc="1099 / CPRS Amounts" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0014" desc="Vendor Comments" dllname="APVCM">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APVCM" desc="Vendor Comments" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0015" desc="Vendors" dllname="APVEN">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APVEN" desc="Vendors" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0407" desc="Vendor Optional Field Values" /><viewcomp name="AP0222" desc="Vendor Contact Selection" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0016" desc="Vendor Groups" dllname="APVGR">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APVGR" desc="Vendor Groups" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0408" desc="Vendor Group Optional Field Values" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0017" desc="Vendor Group Statistics" dllname="APVGS">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APVGS" desc="Vendor Group Statistics" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0018" desc="Remit-To Locations" dllname="APVNR">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APVNR" desc="Remit-To Locations" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0409" desc="Remit-To Location Optional Field Values" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0019" desc="Vendor Statistics" dllname="APVSM">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APVSM" desc="Vendor Statistics" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0020" desc="Invoice Batches" dllname="APIBC">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APIBC" desc="Invoice Batches" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0021" desc="Invoices" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0021" desc="Invoices" dllname="APIBH">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APIBH" desc="Invoices" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0020" desc="Invoice Batches" /><viewcomp name="AP0022" desc="Invoice Details" /><viewcomp name="AP0023" desc="Invoice Payment Schedules" /><viewcomp name="AP0402" desc="Invoice Optional Fields" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0022" desc="Invoice Details" dllname="APIBD">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APIBD" desc="Invoice Details" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0021" desc="Invoices" /><viewcomp name="AP0020" desc="Invoice Batches" /><viewcomp name="AP0401" desc="Invoice Detail Optional Fields" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0023" desc="Invoice Payment Schedules" dllname="APIBS">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APIBS" desc="Invoice Payment Schedules" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0021" desc="Invoices" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0024" desc="Invoice Detail Comments" dllname="APIBT">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APIBT" desc="Invoice Detail Comments" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0025" desc="Documents" dllname="APOBL">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APOBL" desc="Documents" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0026" desc="Document Sched. Payments" dllname="APOBS">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APOBS" desc="Document Sched. Payments" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0027" desc="Document Payments" dllname="APOBP">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APOBP" desc="Document Payments" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0029" desc="Posted Payments" dllname="APPYM">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APPYM" desc="Posted Payments" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0030" desc="Payment and Adjustment Batches" dllname="APBTA">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APBTA" desc="Payment and Adjustment Batches" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0031" desc="Payments/Adjustments" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0031" desc="Payments/Adjustments" dllname="APTCR">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APTCR" desc="Payments/Adjustments" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0030" desc="Payment and Adjustment Batches" /><viewcomp name="AP0032" desc="Miscellaneous Payments" /><viewcomp name="AP0033" desc="Applied Payments" /><viewcomp name="AP0406" desc="Payment/Adjustment Optional Fields" /><viewcomp name="AP0170" desc="Advance Credits" /><viewcomp name="AP0069" desc="Payment Tax Withholdings" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0032" desc="Miscellaneous Payments" dllname="APTCN">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APTCN" desc="Miscellaneous Payments" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0031" desc="Payments/Adjustments" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0033" desc="Applied Payments" dllname="APTCP">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APTCP" desc="Applied Payments" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0031" desc="Payments/Adjustments" /><viewcomp name="AP0034" desc="Adjustment G/L Distributions" /><viewcomp name="AP0048" desc="Create Open Document List" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0034" desc="Adjustment G/L Distributions" dllname="APTCU">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APTCU" desc="Adjustment G/L Distributions" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0033" desc="Applied Payments" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0035" desc="Selection Criteria Header" dllname="APSLH">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APSLH" desc="Selection Criteria Header" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0036" desc="Selection Criteria Details" /><viewcomp name="AP0411" desc="Selection Criteria Opt. Fields" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0036" desc="Selection Criteria Details" dllname="APSLD">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APSLD" desc="Selection Criteria Details" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0035" desc="Selection Criteria Header" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0037" desc="Payment G/L Distributions" dllname="APTRK">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APTRK" desc="Payment G/L Distributions" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0038" desc="Posting Error Messages" dllname="APPTER">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APPTER" desc="Posting Error Messages" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0039" desc="Post Invoices" dllname="APIVPT">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0040" desc="Post Payments and Adjustments" dllname="APPYPT">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0041" desc="Revaluation" dllname="APUNGL">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0042" desc="Create G/L Batch" dllname="APGLTR">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0043" desc="Age Documents" dllname="APAGE">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0044" desc="Process Year End" dllname="APYREN">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0045" desc="Integrity Checker" dllname="APINTCK">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APINTCK" desc="Integrity Checker" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0047" desc="Update Statistics" dllname="APSTAT">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0048" desc="Create Open Document List" dllname="APPOOP">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APPOOP" desc="Create Open Document List" />
</viewtablelist>
<viewcomplist>
<viewcomp name="AP0030" desc="Payment and Adjustment Batches" /><viewcomp name="AP0031" desc="Payments/Adjustments" /><viewcomp name="AP0032" desc="Miscellaneous Payments" /><viewcomp name="AP0033" desc="Applied Payments" /><viewcomp name="AP0034" desc="Adjustment G/L Distributions" /></viewcomplist>
</view>
<view name="AP0049" desc="Clear Fully Paid Documents" dllname="APPREN">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0050" desc="Clear Vendor Comments" dllname="APPGCM">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0051" desc="Clear Statistics" dllname="APPGST">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0052" desc="Delete Inactive Records" dllname="APPGIA">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0054" desc="Return Payments" dllname="APPYRV">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0055" desc="Update Print Status" dllname="APBPPU">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0056" desc="Generate System Batch" dllname="APSYGN">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0057" desc="Control Payments" dllname="APCTRL">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0058" desc="Print Checks" dllname="APCHKS">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0059" desc="Clear Deleted and Posted Batches" dllname="APBCTU">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0060" desc="Payment Advices" dllname="APADV">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APADV" desc="Payment Advices" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0061" desc="Restart" dllname="APRSTRT">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APRSTRT" desc="Restart" />
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0062" desc="AP Drill Down" dllname="APDLDN">
<viewtablelist>
</viewtablelist>
</view>
<view name="AP0063" desc="Revaluation Details" dllname="APRVL">
<viewtablelist>
<table name="APRVL" desc="Revaluation Details" />
</viewtablelist>
</application>
<footer />
</pagebody>
</page>
```

XSL Code:

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

```
  <xsl:import href="aomPage.xsl" />
  <xsl:import href="notePage.xsl" />
  <xsl:import href="appPage.xsl" />
  <xsl:import href="viewPage.xsl" />
  <xsl:import href="tablePage.xsl" />
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Template for html head section. -->
  <xsl:template match="pagehead">
    <head><meta charset="windows-1252">
      <meta name="generator" content="{generator}" />
      <meta name="keywords" content="{keywords}" />
      <title>
        <xsl:value-of select="pagetitle"/>
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,print" href="base_portal.css" />
    </head>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Template to match the main body of the html file -->
  <xsl:template match="pagebody">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-imports/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Template for boilerplate header info. Not to confuse with "pagehead" which is the html head. -->
  <xsl:template match="header">
    <!-- <img height="67" src="/irj/go/km/docs/sageKM/Assets/header.gif" width="594" /> -->
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Template for boilerplate footer info. -->
  <xsl:template match="footer">
    <!-- <img height="24" alt=" " src="/irj/go/km/docs/sageKM/Assets/sage_25.gif" width="594" /> -->
    <p class="footer">
        This page was generated on <xsl:value-of select="/page/pagehead/pagedate"/>
    </p>
    <p class="footer">
      © 2020 Sage Software, Inc. All rights reserved. Reproduction of
      part or all of the contents in any form is prohibited unless for personal use.
      None of the content of this article may be copied or otherwise incorporated into
      any other document, publication or other work in any form (whether written,
      electronic or other format).
    </p>
    <p class="footer">
      Sage Software, Inc. makes no warranties, representations or
      undertakings about any of the content of articles (including, without
      limitation, any as to the quality, accuracy, completeness or fitness for any
      particular purpose of such content).
    </p>
    <!-- <img height="23" src="/irj/go/km/docs/sageKM/Assets/sage_29.gif" width="594" /> -->
    <xsl:comment> START OF SmartSource Data Collector TAG </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:comment> Copyright (c) 1996-2006 WebTrends Inc.  All rights reserved. </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:comment>$DateTime: 2006/03/01 12:51:54 $ </xsl:comment>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <xsl:comment>
        var gDomain="webtrack.bestsoftware.com";
        var gDcsId="dcs9oujaa1000043l9dkb2tq6_7i6e";
        var gFpc="WT_FPC";
        var gConvert=true;
        if ((typeof(gConvert)!="undefined")&amp;&amp;gConvert&amp;&amp;(document.cookie.indexOf(gFpc+"=")==-1)&amp;&amp;(document.cookie.indexOf("WTLOPTOUT=")==-1)){document.write("&lt;SCR"+"IPT TYPE='text/javascript' SRC='"+"http"+(window.location.protocol.indexOf('https:')==0?'s':'')+"://"+gDomain+"/"+gDcsId+"/wtid.js"+"'&gt;&lt;/SCR"+"IPT>");
        }
      </xsl:comment>
    </script>
    <script src="/irj/go/km/docs/sageKM/Assets/dcs_tag.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <noscript>
      <img ALT="" BORDER="0" NAME="DCSIMG" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1" SRC="https://webtrack.bestsoftware.com/dcs9oujaa1000043l9dkb2tq6_7i6e/njs.gif?dcsuri=/nojavascript&amp;WT.js=No" />
    </noscript>
    <xsl:comment> END OF SmartSource Data Collector TAG </xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the live website that is working on windows os browsers.
https://xml.nologicapps.com/AOM/AP.xml

Comment: Does a browser on a normal Mac machine allow you to open the browser's developer console (on Windows that is done with F12)? Check there is the browser shows any errors or warning giving an idea what failed.

Comment: I tried to load the page with Google Chrome on Windows and it doesn't show anything, the error console shows several errors in https://xml.nologicapps.com/AOM/pageTemplate.xsl.

Comment: The main culprit seems to be `<meta charset="windows-1252">` which is not closed properly.

Comment: @MartinHonnen even after closing the meta tag didn't made any difference. also the pageTemplate.xsl, I am able to load properly.